I am facing an issue while upgrading angular version from 11 to 16
d3 is 4.10 version, Node is 18 and angular 16 now I upgraded @swimlane/ngx-charts" from 13 to 20 version. But pie chart is not showing. Here I can see legends but not pie chart. what is the issue please.
I tried with css properties also is there any display problem. But I didn't get resolved. Could you suggest any solution?
Explained problem in above description
